# How do I avoid losing program focus after subprocess.call?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pyautogui

I am trying to extract data from a program; its raw data files are encrypted XMLs so my plan is to start the program, then use mouse control commands (e.g. pyautogui) to copy / paste the data.

So far I'm falling at the first hurdle; when I run subprocess.call to start the program, the program gets window focus and my subsequent code doesn't execute until I manually close the program.

```
workingFolder = self.get_working_folder()  # get path where raw data is

subprocess.call('Path\Program.exe')  # works, Program.exe starts

print(workingFolder)  # this doesn't execute until I close the Program window
```

EDIT: After further testing I have answered my own question - subprocess.Popen was in fact what I needed, despite my initial doubts about it!  Thanks to anyone who looked at my question :).

```
workingFolder = self.get_working_folder()

subprocess.Popen('Path\Program.exe')

print('This works')
```